# Conditional table construction with datatool

Tags: tables, conditionals, rules, datatool

The following minimal example creates a 3-row table width a horizontal rule separating rows 2 and 3:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,datatool,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
fieldA,fieldB,fieldC
A,,textA
B,,textB
C,X,textC
\end{filecontents*}
%D,X,textD% Add this row to the above file... Booooooom!

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[keys={fieldA,fieldB,fieldC}]{data}{data.txt}

\makeatletter
\gdef\tabulardata{}
\DTLforeach*{data}
  {\fieldA=fieldA,\fieldB=fieldB,\fieldC=fieldC}{%
  \DTLifnullorempty{\fieldB}{%
    \gdef\tabularrule{}% No rule
  }{% \fieldB is not NULL nor empty
    \gdef\tabularrule{\noexpand\arrayrulecolor{black!15}\noexpand\cmidrule{1-3}\noexpand\arrayrulecolor{black}}% Grey rule
  }
  \g@addto@macro\tabularrule{\fieldA}% Append \fieldA to \tabularrule
  \protected@xdef\tabulardata{\tabulardata%
    \tabularrule% Insert tabular rule + \fieldA
    & \fieldB & \fieldC \tabularnewline
  }% Construct new tabular row
  }
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  Field A & Field B & Field C \\
  \midrule
  \tabulardata
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip]\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If I insert the commented fourth-row `D,X,textD` into the file `data.txt`, the example doesn't compile any more. Why is that? It *should* output another rule with another row:

[image]

Ideally I'd like the following output, where the `\cmidrule` is only placed before the first occurrence of a non-NULL/empty `\fieldB`:

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  Field A & Field B & Field C \\
  \midrule
  A &   & textA \\
  B &   & textB \\
  \arrayrulecolor{black!15}\cmidrule{1-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}
  C & X & textC \\
  D & X & textD \\
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip]\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\noexpand` expands to nothing do on the second application of `protected@xdef` it os not there and the commands are unprotected. You need a mechanism that keeps them unexpanded on every application of xdef:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,datatool,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
fieldA,fieldB,fieldC
A,,textA
B,,textB
C,X,textC
D,X,textD
\end{filecontents*}
%D,X,textD% Add this row to the above file... Booooooom!

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[keys={fieldA,fieldB,fieldC}]{data}{data.txt}

\makeatletter
\gdef\tabulardata{}
\DTLforeach*{data}
  {\fieldA=fieldA,\fieldB=fieldB,\fieldC=fieldC}{%
  \DTLifnullorempty{\fieldB}{%
    \gdef\tabularrule{}% No rule
  }{% \fieldB is not NULL nor empty
    \gdef\tabularrule{\arrayrulecolor{black!15}\cmidrule{1-3}\arrayrulecolor{black}}% Grey rule
  }
      {\let\arrayrulecolor\relax
    \let\cmidrule\relax
\g@addto@macro\tabularrule{\fieldA}% Append \fieldA to \tabularrule
  \protected@xdef\tabulardata{\tabulardata%
    \tabularrule% Insert tabular rule + \fieldA
    & \fieldB & \fieldC \tabularnewline
  }}% Construct new tabular row
  }
\makeatother

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{c} }
  \toprule
  Field A & Field B & Field C \\
  \midrule
  \tabulardata
  \\[-\normalbaselineskip]\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, so the key here is to redefine the macros you don't want expanded as `\relax`. Good trick.